# Windows Form Tab Control Flickers with Background

Tags: c#, vb.net, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer

I have a panel on a windows form. A form is loaded into the panel based off what button they click. One of these forms that's loaded into the panel has a tab control. The background of the form is an image and every time i switch between tabs, the form flickers. When I set the background image to nothing or a solid color, it works fine so it has to be the image. Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this.DoubleBuffered should be enough. Try to make the image have the right size and make it 32bpp.

Comment: Hmm, my crystal ball says that it is tab control that flickers.  It uses transparency for the tab strip, you see the form behind the tabs.  That gets expensive with a BackgroundImage and the image has a poor pixel format or requires significant rescaling to fit.  Double-buffering doesn't fix that, you need to pre-scale the image.  Use 32bppPArgb to make it fast.

Comment: my application varies from surface pro to windows desktop so i almost have to set the background image layout to 'Stretch' or it would work fine by setting that to none. The doubleBuffered property seems like it helps a lot and will get feedback with it.

Comment: What is 32bppPArg exactly and how do i convert it to that? Never heard of doing that before

Answer (score 0):

Images are expensive to draw, especially on form backgrounds. The only thing that I've found to help this is to set the `BackgroundImageLayout` to `None`, which helped reduce flicker in an application that I had developed.

You can also try setting the `DoubleBuffered` property to `true` but I'm not sure how much mileage you will get out of that.

The problem is that when a control that is placed on the form has to redraw (as in when changing tab pages), everything underneath that control has to be redrawn as well. This causes your form background to invalidate and redraw, sometimes multiple times as the invalidation happens on multiple controls (they don't batch).

Comment: So every time the tab is hit, the form has to redraw that background image on the form? I tried looking into setting my background image at the beginning and calling all my forms with a transparent background but i wasnt able to do that. The theory was correct but creating a form that is transparent doesnt seem like its possible.

Comment: You can create transparent forms (using the `Opacity` property) or shaped forms (search google). But yes, everytime a tab is hit, the form invalidates (with regions, but thats getting into dirty details), so it has to redraw the background, usually multiple times (which is why it flickers, not just blinks once).

Comment: well i thought the best approach would be to set that background image at start up so it only has to be created once and not everytime a form loads. I tried using the opacity property but never had any luck with them. The double buffer property looks like it has helped as well as the backgroundimagelayout = none. Transparent forms might fix it if i could get it to work over an image.

Comment: Also, note that images are much slower to draw with when their pixel format is not PArgb32.  Converting your images to PArgb32 can literally speed up your drawing by a factor of 10.  It may also need to be unscaled to reap the full performance benefits.

Comment: do any of you all have an example code or website where i can convert an image to PArgb32. Seems like this might help tremedously. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To address your follow-up question about converting to PArgb32, the following code will do the trick:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Bitmap originalBmp;
var converted = new Bitmap(originalBmp.Width, originalBmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
{
    g.DrawImage(0, 0, originalBmp);
}
```

You'll still need to use double-buffered controls to reduce flicker, but converting your images to PArgb32 ought to speed up the drawing considerably.

Comment: Thanks! Will follow up later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flicker free tab panel to overcome this issue:

Here is sample code for panel control:

```
public partial class NonFlickerPanel : Panel
{
   public NonFlickerPanel() : base()
   {
          this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
                              ControlStyles.UserPaint 
                              ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, 
                              true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked perfect without flicker when use png as background on tab page

```
public partial class CtechTabPage : TabPage
{
    public CtechTabPage()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Prevent flicker on your custom control
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Exception(ex);
        }
    }
}

// Convert png to light png
Bitmap pngBackground = new Bitmap(Settings.Default.Background);
Bitmap lightBackground = new Bitmap(pngBackground.Width, pngBackground.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(lightBackground))
{
    g.DrawImage(pngBackground, 0, 0);
}
// Put light png to BackgroundImage
YourCtechTabPage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
YourCtechTabPage.BackgroundImage = lightBackground;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into the `DoubleBuffered` property of the `Image` and/or `TabControl`/

If you set it to true, the flickering will probably stop.

Comment: thanks for the great answer, also i dont know why you have negative review